# I want to bind CountDownManager and show the changing data in the label

Tags: swift, data-binding

I want to make a Timer Countdown Manager and update the texts by subtracting the data from the current time and capturing the remaining time in hours, minutes and seconds but I cannot trigger the bind function so the data does not change

```
class CountdownManager {
    var onUpdate: ((String, String, String) -> Void)?
    
    private var timer: Timer?
       
       func startCountdown(from date: Date) {
           timer?.invalidate() // Mevcut timer'ı iptal et
           
           timer = Timer(fire: date, interval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
               guard let self = self else { return }
               let currentDate = Date()
               let calendar = Calendar.current
               let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: date)
               
               let hours = String(components.hour ?? 0)
               let minutes = String(components.minute ?? 0)
               let seconds = String(components.second ?? 0)
               
               self.onUpdate?(hours, minutes, seconds)
           }
           RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
       }
       
       func stopCountdown() {
           timer?.invalidate()
       }
}
```

This is my manager.

```
class TimeCountDownCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    private let bgView = UIView()
    private let dateStackView = UIStackView()
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let infoDateLabel = UILabel()
    private var countDownStackView = CountDownStackView()
    let countDownManager = CountdownManager()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupBackgroundView()
        setupDateStackView()
        setupCountDownStackView()
        titleLabel.text = "LAUNCH DATE"
        infoDateLabel.text = "2020.03.01"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    private func setupBackgroundView() {
        bgView.configureView(bgColor: .black,
                                     cornerRadius: 8)
        addSubview(bgView)
        bgView.edgesToSuperview()
    }
    
    private func setupDateStackView() {
        bgView.addSubview(dateStackView)
        bgView.addSubview(countDownStackView)
        dateStackView.axis = .vertical
        dateStackView.alignment = .fill
        dateStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        titleLabel.customizeLabel(textColor: .white)
        infoDateLabel.customizeLabel(textColor: .white)
        dateStackView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        dateStackView.addSubview(infoDateLabel)
        dateStackViewSetConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupCountDownStackView() {

        countDownStackView.bind(to: countDownManager )
        let currentDate = Date()
        let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 10, to: currentDate)!
        countDownStackView.countdownManager?.startCountdown(from: endDate)

        countDownStackViewSetConstraints()
    }
}
```

Collection view cell this is where I call the custom stack view

```
final class CountDownStackView: UIStackView {
    
    var countdownManager: CountdownManager?
       
       func bind(to countdownManager: CountdownManager) {
           self.countdownManager = countdownManager
           countdownManager.onUpdate = { [weak self] hours, minutes, seconds in
               let data: [[String]] = [
                   ["\(hours)", "Hour"],
                   [":", " "],
                   ["\(minutes)", "Minute"],
                   [":", " "],
                   ["\(seconds)", "Second"],
               ]

               self?.configure(withData: data)
           }
       }
    
    func configure(withData data: [[String]]) {
          axis = .horizontal
          distribution = .equalSpacing
          alignment = .center
          spacing = 5

          for (column, rowData) in data.enumerated() {
              var labels = [UILabel]()
              for (row, text) in rowData.enumerated() {
                  let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
                  label.font = row == 0 ? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 5)
                  label.textColor = column + 1 == data.count ? .systemGray : .white
                  label.text = text
                  label.textAlignment = .left
                  labels.append(label)
              }
              let verticalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: labels)
              verticalStackView.axis = .vertical
              verticalStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
              verticalStackView.alignment = .leading
              verticalStackView.spacing = 0

              addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)
          }
      }
}
```

here is the custom stack view please specify if I am missing information

Comment: Please formulate a clear question describing the issue, writing "I want to" is vague and more of a request than a question.

Comment: of course I updated